# Is it possible to start a new class if a certain item is selected in a spinner?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, spinner

I'm working on a project and I have certain requirements.

One of them is usage of a `Spinner` and I want to use this `Spinner` to make a sort of menu where you can go back to the main screen and such.

Is it possible to have the spinner react by changing classes whenever the user clicks on a certain item?

Comment: it i possible by getting selected item in spinner and using validations by if we will check which one selected and write intent in that

Comment: below code is correct use that will help you

Comment: Check the answer below, there is one listener and 2 ways to achieve, mentioned them with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Try something like this,**

**1> Use Else If ladder to redirect according to position**

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

         // perform action by comparing position

             if(position==0){
                startActivity(new Intent(this,newClass.class));
               }
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

**Or**

**2> Use Switch Case to redirect according to position**

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

         // perform action by comparing position

                switch(position){
                        case 0:
                             startActivity(new Intent(this,newClass.class));
                             break;
                        case 1:
                             startActivity(new Intent(this,newClass.class));                                
                             break;
                       default:
                             break;
               }
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! The switch case will help in the future when I have to add more to the spinner.

Comment: Yeah! That's why I wrote both the cases with example

Comment: Happy Coding !!

Comment: hahah edited from my answer as i already mentioned an upvote will be helpfull

Comment: you already got an upvote. Also, we both answered on same time, diff was I placed a rough ans first and then formatted the same. So its showing edited. there was a split seconds diff between our answers

Answer (score 3):

Set this to spinner it works like a charm

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) 
            {
                if (position == 1)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
                    MyActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) 
            {
                // To do ...
            }

        });
```

> If you have many items in spinner you can also use `switch` insted of
>   if else if conditions

Comment: I tried exactly this except I used = instead of == Thank you!

Comment: never mind you can use switch case if you have many options as I mentioned

Comment: For now I only have one option so I'll be using this method, but in the future I'm adding more so I'll use the switch method mentioned above for that. Thank you for the help!